# Accidentally set the FileZilla option to "Upload overwrite everything"

Tags: ftp, filezilla

How can I change that setting?

I want to upload files only if they are newer than the version in the FTP server.

Is there a reset setting options that I can use without erasing my FTP connection settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a setting that you can change.  It is under `Edit > Settings > Transfers > File Exists Action`
In your case you would change the setting that said "Uploads" to "Overwrite file if source file newer"

Comment: This answer is no longer correct; the new behavior is as described by @Imperative.

Answer (score 12):

In the latest version, you can find the settings at `Transfer > Default File Exists Action`

[image: latest settings menu screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

October 2017 - It is

```
Transfer
Default File Exists Action
```

Then you can set it however you like.

BUT, your question is about the concern of overwriting the FTP connection settings.

And here's the rub:  It does not save this setting in the FTP connection.  It is session-wide, regardless of which connections you use, or how many are used before FileZilla is closed...

In other words, you have to set it every time you start FileZilla.  If you forget and begin a transfer, you can change it while it is transferring, and wherever it is in the queue it will then begin using the new setting.

**So your answer is that you do not need to worry about it resetting your FTP connection, nor its settings.**